# How to in SQL return first found primary key for criteria that has duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

```
Id, Class1, Class2, Class3
1     1        2      3
2     2        3      3
3     1        2      3
```

When exact duplicate rows (Class1,Class2,Class3) appear apart from the primary key I want to take the first record found and ignore further records with that same fields.

So 
I want the output to be

```
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  3
```

I can't use distinct as I want to return the primary key.

I am using Sql Server 2012.

What SQL can give me the desired output?

I have other fields I'm interested in to get from the output that varies but the 3 criteria fields is Class1,Class2,Class3 which  I don't want to duplicate in my output. I am not looking to eliminate duplicates as I just want to take the first record found for the duplicate and ignore the remaining.

Take note: This is a implied example but my real table has hundred of thousands of rows so performance is important.

Comment: Do you have other fields in the table that you're interested in? For example if you had `{ID , FirstName, LastName, Addr}` and you wanted to used first and last to identify dups but wanted the addr with the "first" id?

Comment: I have other fields I'm interested in to get from the output that might vary but the 3 criteria fields is Class1,Class2,Class3 is what I don't want to duplicate in my output. I am not looking to eliminate duplicates as I just want to take the first record found for the duplicate and ignore the remaining duplicate records.

Comment: If that's the case you'll need to use `ROW_NUMBER` or `WHERE ID in  (SELECT MIN..` The simple Min won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following:

```
select * from t1 where ID in(select min(Id) FROM t1 group by Class1, Class2, Class3)
```

Example Demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88fab

Answer (score 2):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT MIN(id), Class1, Class2, Class3
FROM table
GROUP BY Class1, Class2, Class3
ORDER BY MIN(id)
```

Comment: Given that the OP [is interested in additional fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904102/how-to-in-sql-return-first-found-primary-key-for-criteria-that-has-duplicates#comment57544670_34904102) this won't work

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte
as
(select *,
row_number() over (partition by class1,class2,class3 order by id ) as rn from #temp
)
select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
                  (Id INT, Class1 INT, Class2 INT, Class3 INT);

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES (1, 1, 2, 3),
       (2, 2, 3, 3),
       (3, 1, 2, 3);
```

Solution:

```
SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, Class1, Class2, Class3
FROM #temp
GROUP BY Class1, Class2, Class3;
```

Results:

[image]